# Highchart Spline with inverted axis categorie text left align

Tags: highcharts

I have used Spline with inverted axes, in that i need categories alignment left side.
"Is committed to advancing the future of technology" at present it is right aligned, now i need left aligned.
Please help me on this.

or example
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-inverted/grid
In the above link i need Monday et.. should be left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but you will need to specify:

- `chart.marginLeft`
- `xAxis.labels.x`
- `xAxis.labels.align` to left

See together: http://jsfiddle.net/fAfC4/

Note that `leftMargin` and `x` are fixed values, so it won't resize in a default way, like does by default.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Now i am getting left align, in my example it has more text so it is coming inside. I want Y axis 0 45 90, 0 should start after the text, please help me. on this how to move Y axis after x axis text, see http://jsfiddle.net/fAfC4/1/

Comment: I'm sorry, but have you even read my answer..? Why didn't you set labels.x and marginLeft? Just added that and works fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/fAfC4/2/

Comment: yes i missed margin left, sorry, Many thanks it worked. Now i want it to be displayed in mobile how to make it comparable with mobile/tab and desktop.

Comment: According to screen resolution set different margin/x/width (in example above values are 240/-240/240, right?).

Comment: You are correct, I have adjusted according to screen size.

Comment: Please help me in getting the scroll bar in the chart, Now I have added more categories http://jsfiddle.net/fAfC4/6/, in this case i need scroll bar. I got the example http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/2226/ in this     scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
but in my example it is not working. your help is highly needed.

Comment: Because to use scrollbar you need to have Highstock license.

Comment: we have license where i need to put that key, Please suggest

Comment: If you have license then just include Highstock library instead of Highcharts.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I have a issue with scrolling, i am able to scroll the x axis categories but opposite categories are not scrolling, please help, in my example AT&T % values are not scrolling.

Comment: i got the answer linkedTo: 0,

Comment: Hi I need your help in scroll bar, client wants only buttons up and down instead of scroll bar, please help, secondly in the tool tip they want only rectangle box, they don't want pointer. please help

Comment: Then disable scrollbar and create your own buttons up/down. That's event better for you, you will have full control of the buttons. About toltip, see that demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sexYF/7/

Comment: For scrolling I have created 2 image arrow buttons, in this case how to take control of moving up and down,Any example will be great help. Many Thanks for the example, In the Highstock.js i have changed the property  shape:'square' the pointer is not coming. I will use your example if required.

Comment: To implement moving up/down use `chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(newMin, newMax)`. For examples see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes).